# Are these two images of Juan Diez Porlier or Francisco Espoz y Mina?

Tags: spain, napoleonic-wars

This [sketch](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_D%C3%ADaz_Porlier#/media/Archivo:La_Ilustraci%C3%B3n_Gallega_y_Asturiana_1880_04_28_Juan_D%C3%ADaz_Porlier.jpg)

[image]

and this miniature clearly derived from it

[image]

occur on the web in several places as both an image of [Francisco](https://historica.fandom.com/wiki/Francisco_Espoz_y_Mina) [Espoz y Mina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Espoz_y_Mina) and [Juan Diaz Porlier](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_D%C3%ADaz_Porlier). Both were well known and recognized Guerrilla leaders in Spain from 1808 to 1813. There is enough facial similarity between the two that I cannot make a certain determination who it is actually of.

Can anyone make a certain determination of the correct subject?

Comment: Any clue as to what the notation Manchon might allude to in the lower right? French Wikipedia turns up nothing of interest.

Comment: @BOB: Google Translate provides "*manchon*" as French for any of muff, cuff, or mantle.

Comment: To my eyes it looks like Porlier (hair cut, body weight) and not at all like Espoz y Mina.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Personal opinions in this matter aren't worth the bits they're typed with. I'm looking for actual provenance, hopefully in Spanish, for either the sketch or the derived miniature that definitely determines who the portrait is or.

Comment: José Fernández Cuevas (1844-1923) was the artist, Antonio Manchón Quílez was probably the engraver.  See https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Ilustraci%C3%B3n_Gallega_y_Asturiana#/media/Archivo:Portada_do_n%C3%BAmero_1_de_La_Ilustraci%C3%B3n_Gallega_y_Asturiana.jpg for another example of their work.  See http://cervantes.dh.tamu.edu/dqiDisplayInterface/Biographies.jsp?role=2#298 for info about Manchon. See http://cervantes.dh.tamu.edu/DQIIMAGES/largeimages/1410/1868-Madrid-Manini-02-005.jpg for an example of Manchon's work.

Comment: @kimchilover: Good work such as your recent comment really should be in an answer - eventually at least. That said - thank you for sharing your *work in progress* so promptly.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  Thanks.  In the meantime: https://books.google.com/books?id=GgmMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR201&lpg=PR201&dq=Antonio+Manch%C3%B3n+Qu%C3%ADlez&source=bl&ots=KgCPfn1iN2&sig=ACfU3U0ief9HXigZ_IwcRqLJqZ4qN66b2Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxgMW737zkAhWNxFkKHSc1BHMQ6AEwEHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Antonio%20Manch%C3%B3n%20Qu%C3%ADlez&f=false is a roughly contemporaneous example of C & M's work, with modern scholarly attribution;  https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Manch%C3%B3n has more about M.